# Applying a table-valued UDF over multiple rows in another table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I have the following UDF:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY FUNCTION sphere_regular_polygon_vertices(
  lon1 float,
  lat1 float,
  s float,
  n integer
)
RETURNS table (i integer, a float, lon2 float, lat2 float)
IMMUTABLE
COMMENT = $$
Construct a regular polygon on the surface of a sphere.

Parameters:
  lon1: Starting longitude (radians)
  lat1: Starting latitude (radians)
  s: Polygon radius (central angle radians: desired surface distance ÷ sphere radius)
  n: Number of vertices (minimum 3 required for valid polygon)

Returned columns:
  i: Row number
  a: Vertex azimuth
  lon2: Vertex longitude (radians)
  lat2: Vertex latitude (radians)
$$
AS $$
select
  i, a, lon2, lat2
from (
  select
    
    row_number() over (order by null) as i,
    
    (n - i) / n * (2 * pi()) as a,
    
    asin(
      sin(lat1) * cos(s) +
      cos(lat1) * sin(s) * cos(a)
    ) as lat2,
    
    lon1 + atan2(
      ( sin(a) * sin(s) * cos(lat1) ),
      ( cos(s) - sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) )
    ) as lon2

    from table(generator(rowcount => n))
)
$$;
```

I can then use this query to construct a single polygon of `GEOGRAPHY` type:

```sql
select
    array_agg([degrees(lon2), degrees(lat2)]) as coordinates,
    st_makepolygon(
      to_geography(
        {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': array_append(coordinates, coordinates[0])}
      )
    ) as polygon
from table(
  sphere_regular_polygon_vertices(
    radians(-105), radians(25),  -- center at 105W, 25N
    2000::float / 6371000,       -- circle radius is 2 km, earth radius is 6371km
    8                            -- 8 vertices
  )
)
```

It's clunky, but it works.

The problem now is that I really want to be able to perform this same procedure for *multiple rows*.

That is, if I have the following data:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE mypoints AS
  SELECT $1::float as lon1, $2::float as lat1, $3::float as radius
  FROM (VALUES
    (-105, 25, 2000),
    (-105, 26, 3000),
    (-107, 27, 4000))
```

How do I apply this UDF to each row in `mypoints`?

I tried:

```sql
SELECT
  array_agg([degrees(lon2), degrees(lat2)]) as coordinates,
  st_makepolygon(
    to_geography(
      {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': array_append(coordinates, coordinates[0])}
    )
  ) as polygon
FROM
  mypoints AS mp,
  LATERAL sphere_regular_polygon_vertices(
    radians(mp.lon1), radians(mp.lat1),  -- center at 105W, 25N
    mp.radius / 6371000,                 -- circle radius is 2 km, earth radius is 6371km
    8                                    -- 8 vertices
  )
```

But I got the error "Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated" with no further information.

Is there some other way to achieve this? Can I write another UDF that somehow wraps this table-valued UDF in a scalar-valued UDF?

Answer (score 2):

do the whole thing as SQL:

### Fixed N:

```
with my_sets(id, lon1, lat1, radius) as (
    SELECT
        SEQ8(),
        $1::float, 
        $2::float, 
        $3::float
  FROM VALUES
    (-105, 25, 2000),
    (-105, 26, 3000),
    (-107, 27, 4000)
), vert_table as (
    select 
        value::int as i
        ,8 as n
    from table(flatten(input=>ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(1, n+1)))
), maths as (
    select 
        m.id
        ,v.i
        ,radians(m.lat1) as la1
        ,radians(m.lon1) as lo1
        ,((n - i) * 2 * pi()) / n as a
        ,m.radius / 6371000.0 as s
        ,asin(
          sin(la1) * cos(s) +
          cos(la1) * sin(s) * cos(a)
        ) as lat2
        ,lo1 + atan2(
          ( sin(a) * sin(s) * cos(la1) ),
          ( cos(s) - sin(la1) * sin(lat2) )
        ) as lon2
    from my_sets as m
    cross join vert_table as v
), aggregated as (
    select 
        id,
        array_agg([degrees(lon2), degrees(lat2)]) within group (order by i) as coordinates
    from maths
    group by 1
)
select 
    id,
    st_makepolygon(
      to_geography(
        {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': array_append(coordinates, coordinates[0])}
      )
    ) as polygon
from aggregated
order by 1;
```

[image]

### Variable N:

```
with my_sets(id, lon1, lat1, radius, n) as (
    SELECT
        SEQ8(),
        $1::float, 
        $2::float, 
        $3::float,
        $4
  FROM VALUES
    (-105, 25, 2000, 8),
    (-105, 26, 3000, 3),
    (-107, 27, 4000, 16)
), vert_table as (
    select 
        value::int as i
    from table(flatten(input=>ARRAY_GENERATE_RANGE(1, 100)))
), crossed as (
    select m.*
        ,v.i
    from my_sets as m
    join vert_table as v
        on v.i <= m.n
), maths as (
    select 
        id
        ,i
        ,radians(lat1) as la1
        ,radians(lon1) as lo1
        ,((n - i) * 2 * pi()) / n as a
        ,radius / 6371000.0 as s
        ,asin(
          sin(la1) * cos(s) +
          cos(la1) * sin(s) * cos(a)
        ) as lat2
        ,lo1 + atan2(
          ( sin(a) * sin(s) * cos(la1) ),
          ( cos(s) - sin(la1) * sin(lat2) )
        ) as lon2
    from crossed
), aggregated as (
    select 
        id,
        array_agg([degrees(lon2), degrees(lat2)]) within group (order by i) as coordinates
    from maths
    group by 1
)
select 
    id,
    st_makepolygon(
      to_geography(
        {'type': 'LineString', 'coordinates': array_append(coordinates, coordinates[0])}
      )
    ) as polygon
from aggregated
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is that currently SQL UDFs in Snowflake are incorporated into the larger query, and that causes errors like `Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated`.

A solution then could be to write the same UDF in Python or JS, then the UDF wouldn't run into that subquery problem.

That would mean translating this logic into JS/Python:

```sql
  select
    
    row_number() over (order by null) as i,
    
    (n - i) / n * (2 * pi()) as a,
    
    asin(
      sin(lat1) * cos(s) +
      cos(lat1) * sin(s) * cos(a)
    ) as lat2,
    
    lon1 + atan2(
      ( sin(a) * sin(s) * cos(lat1) ),
      ( cos(s) - sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) )
    ) as lon2

    from table(generator(rowcount => n))
```

Comment: So it sounds like the answer is "you can't do that", right?

Comment: Note that in this case I was specifically trying to rewrite some Python UDFs as SQL UDFs! My current Python implementation uses `pyproj` which is already vectorized.

Comment: I guess @simeon was able to do it as SQL. I wish the question had mentioned that you already tried Python - but anyways, there's a great answer for SQL now,